# Issue with Java FTP library Jsch

Tags: java, jsch, apache-commons-vfs

I am using Java 1.7 , jsch 0.1.54 and commons-vfs2 2.1.

This is the code i am using :

```
JSch.setConfig("kex", "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1");
    final StandardFileSystemManager manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();

    try {
final FileSystemOptions opts = new FileSystemOptions();

    FtpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, false);
    FtpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setPassiveMode(opts, true);

    // SSH Key checking
    SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(opts, "no");
    // Root directory set to user home
    SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, false);

    // Timeout is count by Milliseconds
    SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setTimeout(opts, 10000);

        manager.init();

        for (final FileFTPHelper fileFTPHelper : filesHelper) {

            final String filename = fileFTPHelper.getFilename();
            final byte[] value = fileFTPHelper.getData();

            final String remoteDestination = fileFTPHelper.getRemoteFolder() + filename;

            String connection1 = null;
            final String userInfo = fileFTPHelper.getUsername() + ":" + fileFTPHelper.getPassword();
            URI uri = null;
            try {
                uri = new URI("sftp", userInfo, fileFTPHelper.getUrl(), fileFTPHelper.getPort(), remoteDestination, null, null);
                connection1 = uri.toString();
            } catch (final URISyntaxException e) {
                throw new ValidationError("Cannot build the URL. Contact your administrator");
            }

            // Create remote file object
            FileObject remoteFile = null;
            this.log.trace("Sending file : " + remoteDestination);

            try {
                this.log.trace(connection1);
                remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(connection1, opts);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                this.log.error(e, "Error sfp");

            }

            OutputStream io = null;
            if (remoteFile != null) {
                remoteFile.refresh();
                this.log.trace("Connected ! : " + remoteFile);

                try {

                    io = remoteFile.getContent().getOutputStream();
                    io.write(value);
                    io.flush();
                    io.close();
                } catch (final IOException e1) {
                } finally {
                    if (io != null)
                        try {
                            io.close();
                        } catch (final Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
                remoteFile.close();
                if (!remoteFile.exists())
                    throw new ValidationError("Issue when sending files over sftp : The file has not been copied on the FTP");

                if (!remoteFile.isFile())
                    throw new ValidationError("Issue when sending files over sftp : The file is not a file");
            }
            else
                throw new ValidationError("Issue when sending files over sftp : Could not resolve file on the FTP");

            System.out.println("File upload success");
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        this.log.error(e, "Error");
        throw new ValidationError("Issue when sending files over sftp : " + e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        manager.close();
    }
```

and the output i get :

```
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - Connecting to ftpqa.aaaa.com port 22
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - Connection established
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - Remote version string: SSH-2.0-Serv-U_15.1.6.26
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - aes256-ctr is not available.
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - aes192-ctr is not available.
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - aes256-cbc is not available.
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - aes192-cbc is not available.
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: server: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: server: ssh-rsa
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: server: aes256-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes256-ctr
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: server: aes256-cbc,rijndael256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes256-ctr
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: server: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: server: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: server: zlib,none
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: server: zlib,none
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: server: 
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: server: 
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: client: none
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: client: none
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: client: 
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - kex: client: 
SftpClientFactory(line 362) - Disconnecting from ftpqa.aaaa.com port 22
```

i got the following exception :

```
  org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException - Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://***:***@ftpqa.aaaa.com/".
  org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException - Could not connect to SFTP server at "ftpqa.aaaa.com".
  com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException - Algorithm negotiation fail
```

i had a look on various website and the Algorithm negotiation fail seems to be related to a missing Algorithm. I added the code  JSch.setConfig("kex", "diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1"); but it's not working as you can see. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed my issue but downloading the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html and install them in java-home\lib\security